# How to erase the first character from all files (on Windows) into a folder using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename

I have a folder of log files recorded as XML. A guy in here made a mess in there and changed the script of creation of those files and insert a '**p**' letter at the beginning. E.g.:

The file name is now: **p**0154656450103.xml

When it should be: 0154656450103.xml

There are about 3,000 files this way. How can I rename them erasing just the first character or just the '**p**' character?

Comment: Why not just use a preexisting program intended for this, like Rename Master?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [os.rename](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename.htm):

```
import os    
os.rename(src, dst)
```

Comment: A site documenting this is:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename.htm